# Invariance in general relativity, university in problems question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, geodesics, invariants

[From Problem #5 here](http://universeinproblems.com/index.php/Equations_of_General_Relativity#Problem_5:_geodesics),

> Free falling particles' worldlines in General Relativity are geodesics of the spacetime, i.e the curves $x^\mu(\lambda)$ with tangent vector $u^\mu=dx^\mu/d\lambda$, such that covariant derivative of the latter along the curve equals to zero:
>   $$u^\mu\nabla_\mu u^\nu=0.$$
>
> In a (pseudo-)Euclidean space the geodesics are straight lines. Obtain the general equation of geodesics in terms of the connection coefficients. Show that the quantity $u^\mu u_\mu$ is conserved along the geodesic.

Is $u^{\mu}u_{\mu}$ not invariant in general relativity? Is this not enough to say that it is constant along a geodesic? Am I understanding something wrong?

Comment: "Invariant" means that it is observed to be the same by different observers passing through _one_ particular spacetime point;  this doesn't imply that the quantity $u_\mu u^\mu$ is the same at _different_ points along the geodesic.  As an (imperfect) analogy, two people using Euclidean coordinates rotated relative to each other will agree that the electric field at a particular point has a particular magnitude;  but that doesn't imply that the electric field has a constant magnitude everywhere in space.

Comment: Makes sense, cheers!

Comment: @ohannukse is it answers your question? If yes, then I request Michael to add the above as an answer below.

Comment: Yep, it definitely answers the question. Thank you. 
@MichaelSeifert bump

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Invariant" in this case means "invariant under Lorentz transformations".  This means that it is observed to be the same by different observers passing through one particular spacetime point;  two different observers with differing velocities will have their observable quantities related by a Lorentz transformation.

However, this doesn't imply that the quantity $u^\mu u_\mu$ is the same at different points along the geodesic.  As an (imperfect) analogy, two people using Euclidean coordinates rotated relative to each other will agree that the electric field at a particular point has a particular magnitude; but that doesn't imply that the electric field has a constant magnitude everywhere in space.

There *can* be invariants along geodesics, if the spacetime has enough symmetry (look up "Killing vector" and "conserved quantity"), but these are always expressed as contractions of $u^\mu$ with another vector (or sometimes tensor) rather than a contraction of $u^\mu$  with itself.